# bundle fails with rake error on vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, rbenv

I've been following the railscast on setting up Vagrant with rails found here:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/292-virtual-machines-with-vagrant

I have rbenv running on vagrant with a slightly more updated version of ruby(1.9.3p125). Everything goes fine until I try to bundle. Here's the error I get:

vagrant@lucid32:/vagrant$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from http:rubygems...
Fetching gem metadata from http:rubygems...
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.0.3)

Errno::EPROTO: Protocol error - /vagrant/bin
An error occurred while installing rake (10.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.

I've tried gem installing that version of rake, then running rbenv rehash which seems to install, but running bundle again still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by downgrading bundler from 1.3.2 to 1.2.5.

```
rvm use @global
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler -v 1.2.5
# switch back to the default gemset
rvm use
bundle install
# everything should work now
```

The only other thing that I changed was I reverted from rvm 1.18.19 to 1.17.10, but I am not positive that step is necessary.